# qx.ui.core.scroll.AbstractScrollArea children shrinking when scrollbar appears

Tags: qooxdoo

I am creating a custom widget by extending qx.ui.core.scroll.AbstractScrollArea. here is the code roughly

```
qx.Class.define("headers.HeadersList", {
  extend : qx.ui.core.scroll.AbstractScrollArea,
  include: [
    qx.ui.core.MRemoteChildrenHandling
  ],

  construct: function() {
    this.base(arguments);
    this.__container = this._createItemsContainer();
    this.getChildControl("pane").add(this.__container);
    },

  members: {
    __container: null,

    _createItemsContainer: function() {
      const layout = new qx.ui.layout.VBox(10);
      const container = new qx.ui.container.Composite(layout);
      container.setPaddingRight(3);
      return container;
    },

    getChildrenContainer: function() {
      return this.__container;
    }
  }
});
```

The contents are added dynamically. The problem is when the scrollbar appears, the contents are getting shrunk in width to make room for the scrollbar.

I made a small playground example to show what I mean http:// tinyurl.com/yygunxya

If you press the "Add TextField" button more than 4 times, the scrollbar appears and the text boxes are getting narrower.

How can the TextBoxes width stay the same with or without the scrollbar visible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the text field not to adjust to the available space you have to
first set your desired width and you have to disallow shrinkage:

```
const textField = new qx.ui.form.TextField(range.toString()).set({
   allowShrinkX: false,
   width: 300
});
```